# Passing parameters to a portlet (WebCenter Portal)

Tags: parameters, portlet, portal, webcenter

I have a page (say page1.jspx) in a webcenter portal application. The page has a portlet. I need to pass some parameters to the portlet, that I already have in my pageFlowScope.

The parameters are in a HashMap  called myParameterMap. myParameterMap has param1, param2 and param3 as keys respective values.

On the pageDef of page1.jspx, in the portlet tag, I tried to set the value of the parameterMap attribute to `#{pageFlowScope.myParameterMap}`

The portlet in the pageDef looks like this:

```
<portlet id=""...
    parameterMap="#{pageFlowScope.myParameterMap}"/>
```

I already have specified the parameters that are there in myParameterMap in the portlet.xml of the Portlet Producer Application and have added it to my portlet

But when I run the application, I get the following message on my console:

```
The parameterMap on PortletBinding PortletTF1_1 contained a key param1 that is not a parameter on the portlet.
The parameterMap on PortletBinding PortletTF1_1 contained a key param2 that is not a parameter on the portlet.
The parameterMap on PortletBinding PortletTF1_1 contained a key param2 that is not a parameter on the portlet.
```

And in my portlet I am not able to fetch the parameters using getParameter.
Can anybody tell me what is the step I am missing here?

Additional Info:
JDeveloper Version: 11.1.1.7.0

Also, my portlet is a taskflow exposed as a portlet. Do I need to set any parameter in the taskflow as well?

Thanks,
Navaneet

Comment: Anybody? i cannot seem to be able to find a solution to this

Answer (score 0):

Did you try exposing the parameters in bindings and passing them to your parameters separately instead of defining an object for the Parameter Hashmap.

You can also use Yannick's code in [this link](http://www.yonaweb.be/setting_portlet_parameter) to send a parameter, also some great insights about inter portlet communication can be found in [this link](http://yonaweb.be/inter_portlet_communication_jsr_286_and_webcenter_11g_ps3)